Weighted average calculation in PowerBI, my measure is summarizing the unweighted values
I have 4 measures to calculate the weighted average for seven regions. I created a table with volumes for all regions.
I then created 4 measures to get the weighted average.
The weights:
  _Weightedpercentages = DIVIDE(SUM(Volumes[Volume]), CALCULATE(SUM(Volumes[Volume]), ALL(Volumes)))

To summarize the Cost of Production for each region per year :
     _TotalRegionCOP = CALCULATE( SUM('CAD$,T,Ha'[Total Input Cost]),FILTER('CAD$,T,Ha','CAD$,T,Ha'[Region] IN VALUES('CAD$,T,Ha'[Region]) &&
'CAD$,T,Ha'[Growing Season] IN VALUES('CAD$,T,Ha'[Growing Season]))) 

To calculate the weighted COP per region/year.
  _WeightedCOP = [_TotalRegionCOP] * [_Weightedpercentages]

To summarize the weighted Cost of Production, and take the average of the summarized values.
 _Weightedavg = VAR SUMofCOP = SUMX(ALLSELECTED(Weights), [_WeightedCOP]) RETURN AVERAGEX(Weights, SUMofCOP)

Up until step 4 all works well. But for some reason, Powerbi is not summarizing the weightedCOP and taking their average. Instead it shows the unweighted COP for each region/year, and if I selected all regions it shows the summarized value. This is my first time working with PowerBI, and I am unsure how to proceed.

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
